# How use callgrind to profiling only a certain period of program execution?

Tags: profiling, valgrind, callgrind

I want to use valgrind to do some profiling, since it does not need re-build the program. (the program I want to profile is already build with “-g")

But valgrind(callgrind) is quite slow ... so here's what I to do:

1. start the server ( I want to profile that server)
2. kind of attach to that server
3. before I do some operation on server, start collect profile data
4. after the operation is done, end collecting profile data
5. analyze the profiling data.

I can do this kind of thing using sun studio on Solaris. (using dbx ). I just want to know is it possible to do the same thing using valgrind(callgrind)?

Thanks

Comment: I hope Valgrind is not your only option.
Have you considered this technique: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)
You can also use **pstack** or **lsstack** to do the same thing. For money, you can get RotateRight/Zoom which is quite good.

Answer (score 42):

You should look at [callgrind documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.limits), and read about callgrind_control.

1. Launch your app : `valgrind --tool=callgrind --instr-atstart=no your_server.x`
2. See 1.
3. *start collect profile data*: `callgrind_control -i on`
4. *end collect profile data*: `callgrind_control -i off`
5. Analyze data with **kcachegrind** or **callgrind_annotate/cg_annotate**

Answer (score 12):

For profiling only some function you can also find useful [`CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cr.start-instr) and `CALLGRIND_STOP_INSTRUMENTATION` from `<valgrind/callgrind.h>` header and using callgrind's `--instr-atstart=no` option as suggested in [Doomsday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3299472/673852).

Comment: I didn't realize that it is still necessary to run your program within valgrind, even with the macros. E.g., `valgrind –tool=callgrind –instr-atstart=no your_server.x`

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what OS - I'm assuming Linux - in which case you might want to look at oprofile (free) or [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com) (not free, but you can get an evaluation licence), both of which are sampling profilers and can profile existing code without re-compilation. Zoom is much nicer and easier to use (it has a GUI and some nice additional features), but you probably already have oprofile on your system.

Comment: Yes, I just see some other guys recommended these 2 tools. For me, the point to use valgrind is it does not root access since I am using a public server to do profiling...

Comment: I think you only need root access to *install* these tools - you should be able to run them without root access, no ? (I use Zoom from a normal non-root account, but that's for local profiling, so I can't be sure about the remote profiling case.)

Comment: I see, thanks. But I still want to know if it is possible to use valgrind to do the same thing. Sometimes when I can not reproduce performance issue, I need to take look at test machine directly, but install profiling software (which collect hardware counter) may impact system performance, and a lot of baseline need adjusted which is not allowed.. So valgrind is still the best option, if I can use it in the way I described in the question.