# Can we use massif to measure only a certain period?

Tags: valgrind, massif

Does valgrind -tool=massif have a similar control like [callgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400025/how-use-callgrind-to-profiling-only-a-certain-period-of-program-execution) to profile memory for only a certain period? Can we turn the profiling on and off during a problem run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Massif does not even have a header with user request macros.

It's not what you're asking, but if you're using Massif you might be interested in the new [xtree result visualization feature](https://fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/valgrind_features/attachments/slides/1821/export/events/attachments/valgrind_features/slides/1821/fosdem2017_mempill.odp), part of the imminent Valgrind 3.13

Comment: When will 3.13 release?

Comment: I believe the target date is 15 June.

Comment: Is http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/valgrind.1.html the release node of 3.13? I did not see the xtree-syscall option discussed in the slides?

Comment: xtree syscall is experimental/unfinished/... --xtree-memory and --xtree-leak (for memcheck) are part of 3.13. Note that by using memcheck + vgdb commands to produce xtree leak reports, you can see what increase/decrease memory you have got during a certain period