# How to use Callgrind to profile specific functions?

Tags: valgrind, profile, callgrind

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400025/how-use-callgrind-to-profiling-only-a-certain-period-of-program-execution), I wrapped my functions with CALLGRIND_xxx_INSTRUMENTATION macros. However, I always get "out of memory".

Here is a simplified version of my program and callgrind would still run out of memory even though I could run callgrind without using the macros.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <valgrind/callgrind.h>

void foo(int i)
{
  printf("i=%d\n", i);
}

int main()
{
   for (int i=0; i<1048576; i++)
   {
     CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION;
     foo(i);
     CALLGRIND_STOP_INSTRUMENTATION;
   }
}
```

To run this, "valgrind --tool=callgrind --instr-atstart=no ./foo >foo.out".

Did I do anything wrong? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION` typical use case is to skip instrumenting the application startup code. If you call it in a loop, then this is costly both in memory and in cpu,
as callgrind will each time re-instrument the code.

If you are interested in only measuring some functions, you should rather
start instrumentation somewhere before the loop, and then use `CALLGRIND_TOGGLE_COLLECT` before/after the function calls you are interested in.
That will use both less cpu and less memory.

If you want to do the above, you should then use the options `--instr-atstart=no` and `--collect-at-start=no`. You then start instrumentation at the relevant place in your program (e.g. after the startup/initialisation code). You can then insert calls to `CALLGRIND_TOGGLE_COLLECT` in the functions you are interested in.

Note that instead of modifying your program to call `CALLGRIND_TOGGLE_COLLECT` for a bunch of functions,
you can also use one or more times the command line option `--toggle-collect=<function>`

Comment: I tried --toggle-collect=foo but it didn't work.  callgrind.out.xxx was empty.

Comment: I just tried, and it works perfectly (debian 9, valgrind git version). I suggest you try with a very small application, only main calling foo. No valgrind client requests. And then do: valgrind --tool=callgrind --instr-atstart=yes --collect-atstart=no --toggle-collect=foo ./simple_test