# attaching callgrind/valgrind to program in mid-way of its execution

Tags: c++, valgrind, callgrind

I use Valgrind to detect issues by running a program from the beginning. 
Now I have memory/performance issues in a very specific moment in the program. Unfortunately there is no feasible way to make a shortcut to this place from the start.

Is there a way to instrument the c++ program ( Valgrind/Callgrind ) in its mid-way execution, like attaching to the process?

**Already answered here:**
[How use callgrind to profiling only a certain period of program execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400025/how-use-callgrind-to-profiling-only-a-certain-period-of-program-execution)

Comment: Even if it's possible, it's often hard to use memory-debugger unless they have the full context at the point of the problems. And asking for a report in the middle of a running program will lead to a lot of false positives as well as false negatives. How complex is it to replicate the problems you have? How long will it take normally? Even if it's a long and complex setup, hopefully you only have to do it twice (once to get information, once to verify a fix). It might be worth taking a day or two to spend time finding, fixing and verifying the issue.

Comment: You mean it takes too much time for a fully instrumented version to reach the middle?

Comment: @CrouchingKitten exactly :( instrumented version is super slow + I am not interested in other defects that might pop-up before that place : [

Comment: Is it composed of multiple modules? I'm not sure if this gives a speed-up, but you can try to use the `-g` compiler parameter only on modules, which you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for help.
Seems It's been already answered here: [How use callgrind to profiling only a certain period of program execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400025/how-use-callgrind-to-profiling-only-a-certain-period-of-program-execution) 
but not marked as answered for some reason.

Summary:
Starting callgrind with instrumentation off

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --instr-atstart=no <PROG>
```

Controling instrumentation ( can be executed in other shell )

```
callgrind_control -i on/off
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to use valgrind on an already running program.

For callgrind, you can however somewhat speed it up by only recording data later during execution.

For this, you might e.g. look at callgrind options

```
    --instr-atstart=no|yes    Do instrumentation at callgrind start [yes]
    --collect-atstart=no|yes  Collect at process/thread start [yes]
    --toggle-collect=<func>   Toggle collection on enter/leave function
```

You can also control such aspects from within your program.

Refer to valgrind/callgrind user manual for more details.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that Callgrind does that slows down execution.

- Counting operations (the collect part)
- Simulating the cache and branch predictor (the instrumentation part). This depends on the `--cache-sim` and `--branch-sim` options, which both default to "no". If you are using these options and you disable instrumentation then I expect that there will be some impact on the accuracy of the modelling as the cache and predictor won't be "warm" when they are toggled.

There are a few other approaches that you could use.

1. Use the client request mechanisms. This would require you to include a Valgrind header and add a few lines that use Valgrind macros `CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION`/`CALLGRIND_STOP_INSTRUMENTATION` and `CALLGRIND_TOGGLE_COLLECT`to start and stop instrumentation/collection. [See the manual](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.clientrequests) for details. Then just run your application under Valgrind with `--instr-atstart=no --collect-atstart=no`
2. Use the gdb [monitor commands](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.monitor-commands). In this case you would have two terminals. In the first you would run Valgrind with `--instr-atstart=no --collect-atstart=no --vgdb=yes`. In the second terminal run `gdb yourapplication` then from the gdb prompt `(gdb) target remote | vgdb`. Then you can use the monitor commands as described in the manual, which include collect and instrumentation control.
3. `callgrind_control`, part of the Valgrind distribution. To be honest I've never used this.

I recently did some profiling using the first technique without cache/branch sim. When I used Callgrind on the whole run I saw a 23x runtime increase compared to running outside of Callgrind. When I profiled only the one function that I wanted to analyze, this fell to about a 5x slowdown. Obviously this will very greatly case by case.